# Shadow achievement that is randomly obtained

Tags: cookie-clicker

How quickly can the [Just Plain Lucky] Shadow Achievement be obtained in Cookie Clicker? And if so, what is the record-holding time for getting this achievement? This is how many seconds since the first ascension in a entire run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Just Plain Lucky" is awarded at random: each second that the game is running, you've got a 1 in 500,000 chance of getting the achievement.  It could happen as soon as you start playing, or it could take weeks.  (Because the random number generator isn't truly random, it's guaranteed to be awarded eventually.)

Answer (score 1):

Well when I played cookie clicker I found that the more you play the higher the chance but if you wish to use cheats create a bookmarklet like this

Make a bookmark and title it whatever you want and the under link use this code
then when playing push that bookmark and you will get the achievment
`javascript:Game.Win(Game.AchievementsById[104].name);`